# How to sum each row with a constant and multiply by a constant

Tags: excel

Hello I've a question about excel in column A I've the following values 100, 200, 300, 400, 500. In column B1 I've a constant 3 in column C1 I've constant 5.

Now I need a formula to do this ((a1+b1)*c1) + ((a2+b1)*c1) + ((a3+b1)*c1) + ((a4+b1)*c1) + ((a5+b1)*c1) + ... ((an + b1) * c1)

In this case the result will be 7575.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what SUMPRODUCT is for:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A5+B1)*C1)
```

[image]

Comment: I was watching sumproduct but I didn't know I was able to do this. Thanks